# How to reuse a Criteria object with hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, pagination, displaytag

I'm trying to do query result pagination with hibernate and displaytag, and Hibernate `DetachedCriteria` objects are doing their best to stand in the way. Let me explain...

The easiest way to do pagination with displaytag seems to be implementing the `PaginatedList` interface that has, among others, the following methods:

```
/* Gets the total number of results. */
int getFullListSize();

/* Gets the current page of results. */
List getList();

/* Gets the page size. */
int getObjectsPerPage();

/* Gets the current page number. */
int getPageNumber();

/* Get the sorting column and direction */
String getSortCriterion();
SortOrderEnum getSortDirection();
```

I'm thinking of throwing my PaginatedList implementation a Criteria object and let it work along theese lines...

```
getFullListSize() {
    criteria.setProjection(Projections.rowCount());
    return ((Long) criteria.uniqueResult()).intValue();
}

getList() {
    if (getSortDirection() == SortOrderEnum.ASCENDING) {
        criteria.addOrder(Order.asc(getSortCriterion());
    } else if (getSortDirection() == SortOrderEnum.DECENDING) {
        criteria.addOrder(Order.desc(getSortCriterion());
    }
    return criteria.list((getPageNumber() - 1) * getObjectsPerPage(),
                         getObjectsPerPage());
}
```

But this doesn't work, because the `addOrder()` or the `setProjection()` calls modify the criteria object rendering it in-usable for the successive calls. I'm not entirely sure of the order of the calls, but the db throws an error on `getFullListSize()` trying to do a "`select count(*) ... order by ...`" which is obviously wrong.

I think I could fix this by creating an object of my own to keep track of query conditions and rebuilding the Criteria object for each call, but that feels like reinventing yet another wheel. Is there a smarter way, possibly copying the Criteria initially passed in and working on that copy?

***Update***:
It looks like `getList` is called first, and `getFullListSize` is called multiple times after, so, as soon as there's an ordering passed in, `getFullListSize` will fail. It would make sense to hit the db only once (in `getList` I'd say) and cache the results, with no need to copy/reset the `Criteria` object, but still...

***Update (again)***:
Forget about that, once I've done the `count` I can't do the `select`, and vice versa. I really need two distinct `Criteria` objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well, DetachedCriteria are Serializable, so you have built-in (if inelegant) deep clone support.  You could serialize the initial criteria to a byte[] once on construction, then deserialize it each time you want to use it.

Comment: Found that suggestion on the hibernate forums, but I'd rather not :-)

Answer (score 49):

```
Criteria.setProjection(null);
Criteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.ROOT_ENTITY);
```

Will effectively "reset" the criteria between the rowCount projection and execution of the criteria itself.

I would make sure your Order hasn't been added before doing the rowCount, it'll slow things down. My implementation of PaginatedList ALWAYS runs a count query before looking for results, so ordering isn't an issue.

Comment: Recommend this be correct answer - more elegant than deep clone.

Answer (score 2):

http://weblogs.asp.net/stefansedich/archive/2008/10/03/paging-with-nhibernate-using-a-custom-extension-method-to-make-it-easier.aspx

In that post I spotted a CriteriaTransformer.clone method.

That should copy the criteria object.

You can also set the projection on your getlist method.

Woops I didn't notice you were referring to java hibernate. Anyway, this http://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?t=939039

forum post should be able to answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

Ugly as it may be I ended up using the serialization trick. I just serialize the `DetachedCriteria` object to a byte array on construction of the `PaginatedList` object and de-serialize it when needed. Ouch.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing worth trying:

implement a generic DAO like [the one suggested on hibernate's site](https://www.hibernate.org/328.html) and pass it to the PaginatedList object, along with a Restrictions object. The PaginatedList object would then do something like

```
Criteria.forClass(myDAO.getPersistentClass())
        .add(myRestrictions)
        .addOrder(<someOrder>)
```

and

```
Criteria.forClass(myDAO.getPersistentClass())
        .add(myRestrictions)
        .setProjection(Projections.rowCount());
```

Haven't tried that yet, but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

There is a better and easy way to clone criteria, just simply:

```
ICriteria criteria = ...(your original criteria init here)...;

var criteriaClone = (ICriteria)criteria.Clone();
```

And getting back to Your problem. For pagination I've made a method, which gives me as a result:

```
1. Total rows count
2. Rows filtered by page & pageSize
In a single query to DB.
```

```
ICriteria criteria = ...(your original criteria init here)...;    
var countCrit = (ICriteria)criteria.Clone();
countCrit.ClearOrders(); // avoid missing group by exceptions

var rowCount = countCrit
    .SetProjection(Projections.RowCount()).FutureValue<Int32>();

var results = criteria
    .SetFirstResult(pageIndex * pageSize)
    .SetMaxResults(pageSize)
    .Future<T>();

var resultsArray = results.GetEnumerable();

var totalCount = rowCount.Value;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public static DetachedCriteria Clone(this DetachedCriteria criteria)
{
   var dummy = criteria.ToByteArray();
   return dummy.FromByteArray<DetachedCriteria>();
}
```